# Is it possible to prevent a child div from inheriting its parent div's controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm wondering if its possible to prevent a child div within a nested div inheriting its parent controller.

```
<div id="parentDiv" ng-controller="parentCtrl">  
   <div id="childDiv" ng-controller="childCtrl"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Imagine I have a scope variable called `name`, how could I ensure that name is not accessible in side `childDiv`.

See [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yw1Rl4Iye84cfKU5B6Hl?p=preview).

It's not problematic to have a child div accessing the variables of its parent controller but it just doesnt feel right. What about naming collisions on so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way to hide variables of a child scope from the parent scope with respect to angular controllers.  The scope of the parent is always available to the scope of the children.  I do have two points that may help.

1) Naming collision may not be a problem as you would expect.  If you set $scope.name in the childCtrl to "testChild", the name variable's value parentCtrl is still "testParent".  The child $scope has access to the parent but does not overwrite/share variables, only objects.

2) If you are worried about naming collision or confusion, I would recommend placing an object on scope and adding properties to that object.  Example: $scope.parentData = { name = "testParent"} and $scope.childData = { name = "testChild"}